# Processing Rmarkdown inside chunks

Tags: r, conditional-statements, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to add a formatted section to a knitr markdown report conditional on some parameters.

E.g.,

````
```{r conditional, eval=outliers, result="asis"}
# If outliers==TRUE, the following section is added to the report
print(
  "# Conditional section

  ## Subsection

  This is here because **outliers==TRUE**!")
```
````

Of course, the above doesn't work at all. How can I modify it so that it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close already. You need to use `cat` instead of `print`.  You will also want to change how you supply your string.  Your section headings won't render with white space in front of them.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
outliers <- TRUE
```

```{r conditional, eval=outliers, results="asis"}
# If outliers==TRUE, the following section is added to the report
cat(
"# Conditional section  

## Subsection

This is here because **outliers==TRUE**!")
```
````

Or alternatively

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
outliers <- TRUE
```

```{r conditional, eval=outliers, results="asis"}
# If outliers==TRUE, the following section is added to the report
cat(
  "# Conditional section  ",
  "## Subsection  ",
  "This is here because **outliers==TRUE**!",
  sep = "\n")
```
````

Comment: The second approach is better, somehow the first approach doesn't yield the subsection-formatting.

Comment: Oddly enough, it's rendering correctly on my machine.  But I'll agree with you that the second is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin! For me, the first approach doesn't render the formatting either, but the second does.